# Mahalanobis Distance critical alpha cutoff

Tags: multivariate-analysis, manova, mahalanobis

I have two predictors and five dependent variables. I'm trying to figure out what the critical alpha cutoff for Mahalanobis distance is for a model with 5 DVs to check for assumption of multivariate outliers before my MANOVA. Can't seem to find the answer anywhere, could anyone help?

Comment: With critical alpha cutoff you mean the number of standard deviations?

Comment: Using Mahalanobis distance to determine outliers is rarely a good idea.  At a minimum, the covariance matrix needs to be estimated with a procedure that is resistant to outliers, for otherwise the outliers can mask their own presence.  The cutoff depends on that as well as what you postulate about the outliers: do you know how many to look for, for instance? Consequently, there are *many* variants of such procedures, depending on the steps used to make them outlier-resistant.  Could you therefore describe in detail the procedure you plan to use?